# Spring Boot + CloudFoundry + Test Unit issue

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I want to make a Unit Test for my application. I am using Spring Boot and CloudFoundry.
When I start "Test File" without cloud connection then I get a mistake in my logs:
*"Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No suitable cloud connector found"*

I tried to use:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
        "spring.cloud.config.enabled:false" })
```

How I can exclude/off a cloud for an Unit test?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I usually add `@Profile("cloud")` on CF-specific configurations. `cloud` profile will be automatically applied in CF env.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case I want to skip CF-specific configurations when Unit Test is started. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app getting Spring Cloud Connectors via the Boot starter (e.g. `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connector`), or do you have an explicit dependency on the Connectors libs (e.g. `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector`)?

If you are using the Boot starter, then the Cloud Connectors autoconfig should not be enabled unless the [`cloud` Spring profile is active](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cloud/CloudAutoConfiguration.java#L49). Make sure that profile is not active when your tests are run.

If you want to explicitly disable Cloud Connectors autoconfig in your test, the [proper syntax](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cloud/CloudAutoConfiguration.java#L53) would be:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
    "spring.cloud.enabled=false" })
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when running in a local environment
The problem in code

```
CloudConfig extends ApplicationCloudConfig {
        // local and cloud configuration code seperated with @Profile.
    }
```

Resolved Code

```
    class Config {
    //... some config code ...
        @Profile("cloud")
        static class CloudConfig extends  ApplicationCloudConfig {
        //cloud config related code 
        }

        @Bean
        @Profile({"local"})
        public DataSource dataSource() {
          //data source config
        }
}
```